# Retrieve only capitalised words inside a String

Tags: java, string

Let's assume we have the following string:

```
String string = "Hello my name Is John doe";
```

I would like to get only the capitalized strings from this string, in this case: `Hello`, `Is`, `John`.

How can I achieve that in Java?

Comment: I hate down voters ... anyone can have any kind of doubts ... better try to solve the prob and help the person

Comment: Firstly, split the string with space which will store it in an array. Then loop through the array and get the first character of the string. Use IsUpper to determine if the character is Upper case.

Comment: Here is the code for my previous comment:

String strings = "Hello my name Is John doe";
        String[] names = strings.Split(' ');
        String upperletter = "";
        for(int a=0; a< names.Length; a++)
        {
            char aa = names[a].Substring(0)[0];
            if(char.IsUpper(aa))
                upperletter += names[a] + ", ";

        }

Answer (score 6):

You could [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) the string and check each part for an uppercase first letter:

```
String string = "Hello my name Is John doe";
List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();

for (String s : string.split(" ")) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0))) {
        result.add(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use regex with word boundary.

```
public static void main(String... strings) {
    String string = "Hello my name Is John doe";
    String[] arr = string.replaceAll("\\b[a-z]\\w+\\b", "").split("\\s+");
    for (String s : arr) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
Hello
Is
John
```

Comment: this is the best solution :)

Comment: @SabaRish - Nope. *Mureinik*'s solution is the best ATM. :)

Comment: @SabaRish - Ya.. That I agree :)

Comment: @SabaRish - I learnt it here on SO :P.. Click on the regex tag and start writing your own regexes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71322/discussion-between-sabarish-and-thelostmind).

Answer (score 0):

Split the string at space characters, then iterate over each split part and check is its first letter is capital.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "My hovercraft is Full of Eels";
    Collection<String> startingWithCapital = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String part : text.split(" ")) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(part.charAt(0))) {
            startingWithCapital.add(part);
        }
    }
    // Just to make sure it works
    for (String part : startingWithCapital) {
        System.out.println(part);
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
My
Full
Eels
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex and loop through all matches:

```
String line = "Hello my name Is John doe";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]\\w+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```